# How to give textarea the same height as its sibling inline-block images?

Tags: html, css, textarea

How to give `textarea` the same height as its sibling inline-block images?

```css
.wrap {
  text-align: center;
}

.rowimg {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 29%;
  margin: 0 2%;
}

.rowtx {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 29%;
  margin: 0 2%;
  height: 100%; // here
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrap'>
  <img class='rowimg' src='ph.jpg' alt='img'>
  <img class='rowimg' src='ph.jpg' alt='img'>
  <textarea class='rowtx'></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: what's the size or ratio of your images ?

Comment: display:flex on wrap? (and remove the height;100%)

Comment: @G-Cyrillus, your snippet is not real, all children, including textarea should be in one row.

Comment: that **is** your own code wrapped into a snippet -/-  . Why did i asked about ratio ? https://jsfiddle.net/3s2kdjp4/

Comment: @G-Cyrillus the code is mine, but snippet is your. Without a real 'src' attr the snippet cannot be real. That's why I avoid the snippet. And images have various aspect ratio.Anyway, Temani Afif solved.

Comment: *- And images have various aspect ratio* **it answers my question** .